# Only the Object's outline is moving instead of object

Tags: modeling

I am very new to blender and facing some problems. In viewport after selection of an object, only outlines of the object are moving while doing any action like dragging, rescalingor another option for that matter, and sometimes if I add some other mesh the first one is disappeared.

[image]